# How to debug why the Java message output is always null?

Tags: java, class, methods, printing, null

Here is the `Message` class I created:

```
public class Message {
  static String toString;
  static String sender;
  static String recipient; 
  static String messageBody ;

  public Message(String Sender, String Recipient){
    sender = Sender ;
    recipient = Recipient ;
    messageBody = "";
  }

  public String getSender(String s){
    sender = s;
    return sender;  
  }
  public String getRecipient(String r){
    recipient = r;
    return recipient;   
  }
  public void append (String a){
    a = messageBody +a; 
  }
  public void toString (String m){
    messageBody = m;
    m = ("From: " + sender + "\nTo: "+ recipient+"\n" + "\n" + messageBody);
    System.out.print(m);
  }
}
```

Following is the `main` method. I need to print using `toString()` method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab8 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Message mess1 = new Message (null, null);       
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String Sender1= Message.sender; 
    String recipient1 = Message.recipient;
    String message = Message.messageBody ;

    System.out.println ("Input Sender Name: ");
    Sender1 = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println ("Input Recipent Name: ");
    recipient1 = keyboard.next();
    do {
      System.out.print ("Input Message: ");
      message = keyboard.next();
    } while (!message.equals("***") );

    System.out.print(Message.toString);
  }
}
```

This prints `null` every time. I also need to include the append method that allows me to change the message body after every line.

Comment: Although this compiles and executes, there are serious problems here. The biggest problem is Message uses `static` fields when you really want instance fields: Delete `static` from Message class.

Comment: i have, then i set a return variable and i still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You've got this all wrong!
There's no need to have a static String field called `toString`, all you need is `toString()` method. But still, **you do not need to print anything inside the `toString()` method**. Just return a String from it.

Change your `toString` method as follows:

```
public String toString (String m) {
  messageBody = m;
  m = ("From: " + sender + "\nTo: "+ recipient+"\n" + "\n" + messageBody);
  return m;
}
```

Then to print it, use following line of code inside your main method:

```
System.out.print(mess1.toString(message));
```

Still, your getters and setters are wrong. Try to read more about getters and setters.

There should be two methods:

- `getSender()`
- `setSender()`

`getSender()` should look like this:

```
public String getSender(){
  return sender;  
}
```

and the `setSender()` should look like this:

```
public void setSender (String sender) {
  this.sender = sender;
}
```

**Same thing goes with Recipient**.